# Fastest way to grab a picture from webcam

Tags: python, image, opencv, optimization, camera

I'm trying to capture an event in real time using a webcam. (maximum delay of 50 - 100 milliseconds is acceptable). Could someone please suggest the fastest way of doing this on python.

This is what I've written, but it's taking about 350 milliseconds

```
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if the webcam is opened correctly
if not cap.isOpened():
    raise IOError("Cannot open webcam")

start = time.time()
ret, frame = cap.read()
end = time.time()
frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

print(end - start)
cv2.imshow('Input', frame)
c = cv2.waitKey(1)

while c!=27:
    continue


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I recently saw in the docs of `imageio` that capturing a frame from webcam there is also a simple oneliner. IMHO I think that the time taken for this is mainly HW dependant - but you could just give it a try and see... https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html

Comment: I'm confused by the example: one way or another, this is *not* the expected [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The only time frame you measure is for `cap.read()`, but you've included code after that.  What portion of this needs to be faster?

Comment: Besides that, as far as I learned here: for timing comparisons use `timeit`, not `time`.

Comment: What takes 350ms? How is `c` going to become 27 in a loop in which it doesn't change? Why are you using Python for something if it is time-critical? You say a maximum delay of 50ms is permissible - 50ms between what and what? Are you running on a Raspberry Pi? What's the camera? What resolution are you acquiring at because you seem happy enough to resize by a factor of 2 so why not acquire at the lower resolution up-front and only transfer 25% as much data?

Comment: What is the frame rate of the camera ?